# insertion into cart does when page refreshes in codeigniter with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am adding items into cart with ajax in codeigniter.
My problem is that the cart got updated when i refreshes page. I have ajaxify it to prevent page refresh. but its not happening. My code is right and there is no error. but still its not working.
my controller code is

```
public function add_to_cart()
  {
    $item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');
    $item_name = $this->input->post('item_name');
    $item_price = $this->input->post('item_price');
    $data = array(

                       'id'      => rand(5,1000),
                       'qty'     => 1,
                       'price'   => $item_price,
                       'name'    => $item_name,


            );

$this->cart->insert($data);

  }
```

my view code is

```
    function insert()
{
var item_id=$("#item_id").val(); 
var item_name=$("#item_name").val();
var item_price=$("#item_price").val();
var dataString = "&item_id=" + item_id + "&item_name=" + item_name + "&item_price=" + item_price;
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "http://localhost/wah/cart_test/add_to_cart",  
        data: dataString,

        success: function()
        {
            alert('hello');
        }
    });
} 



   <form id="form">
                    <input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id" value={{data.id}}> <input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value={{data.item_name}}> <input type="hidden" id="item_price" name="item_price" value={{data.price}}>
                    <p><a href="#" onclick="insert()" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a></p>
                     </form>
```

Comment: When do you call that insert() in view?

Comment: by mistake i add other code, i have updated the correct code above.

Comment: do you mean it doesn't insert to cart or it needs refresh to trigger the changes ?

Comment: refresh is required to trigger the changes.

Comment: In your success function of ajax you need to write the code to display it in cart. On your ajax the items will be inserted to cart, but the current page doesn't know about that change, ie why when you refresh the page you see the updated cart.

Comment: These are some good tutorials you can refer to: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-ajax-powered-shopping-cart--net-486 http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/

Comment: Noticed another thing also, you are using POST in your ajax and passing the variables in url, are you getting those values in your ajax page? Also are you getting the success alert?

Answer (score 1):

the concept of the cart is to add the cart array in a session 
so the php will not feel the changes until you reload the page

so you have to append the table with javascrip

```
// in controller     
public function add_to_cart()
      {
        $item_id = $this->input->post('item_id');
        $item_name = $this->input->post('item_name');
        $item_price = $this->input->post('item_price');
        $data = array(

                           'id'      => rand(5,1000),
                           'qty'     => 1,
                           'price'   => $item_price,
                           'name'    => $item_name,


                );

        $this->cart->insert($data);
        echo json_encode($data) ;

          }




 // in your javascript 
     $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "http://localhost/wah/cart_test/add_to_cart",  
            data: dataString,



    success: function(data)
        {

         // just replace YOUR-TABLE-ID with table id 
         //and complete the tr you want to append

          var tr = "<tr><td>"+data.id+"</td><td>"+data.name+"</td></tr>";
          $("#YOUR-TABLE-ID tr:last").after(tr);
        }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening when you try to use $item_id instead radnom number:

```
$data = array(
    'id'      => $item_id,
    'qty'     => 1,
    'price'   => $item_price,
    'name'    => $item_name,
);
```

Comment: Try with preventing default:
`function insert(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of code
}`
Also, would be good to wrap it over jQuery .on() or .click() method, 
something like:
`$("#item_id").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of code
});`